# Android - move image view

Tags: android, layout, android-activity

I want to use the layout, created in xml and 
move the imageView in the place, where screen is touched.
Walking around and stuck completely.
What is wrong? 
Is it ok to put all this code into onCreate, or I should use other methods?

```
 public class Game2 extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

    ImageView myBall;
    static TextView textElement;
    static float x, y = 0;
    static float newX, newY;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.field);

        textElement = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        textElement.setText("Starting");

        myBall = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_ball);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        switch (me.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            newX = me.getX();
            newY = me.getY();
            myBall.setX(newX);
            myBall.setY(newY);
            break;
        }
        myBall.invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that one problem is with invalidate...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in the given code, you're only drawing the ball once at the very beginning of your activity. `onCreate()` is only called once, when the `Activity` is first [brought to life](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) within the operating system. You're using `invalidate()` to force a redraw of the `ImageView`, so I believe that if you call `invalidate()` again after updating the position of the ball in your `onTouch()` method, you should get the behaviour you're after.

Also, you appear to only be assigning the values to `newX` and `newY`, and not the actual position of the ball. You'll need to call `setX()` and `setY()` again in order to pass these updated values.

Comment: tried to call invalidate in onTouch() but it still doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        switch (me.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            newX = me.getX();
            newY = me.getY();
            myBall.setX(newX);
            myBall.setY(newY);
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: and how to use invalidate?

Answer (score 0):

Actually my friends were right.
But the code didn't work because I haven't set onTouchListenner.

So I set layout id

```
android:id="@+id/field_layout"
```

and added in onCreate:

```
 LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.field_layout);
 myLayout.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

now everything is working.
Thanks a lot!